# Rotating a whole layout around it's center

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation

I'm trying to implement a rotating dialer as of my client's request.
I've made a rotating ImageView like the one that's [listed on tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868)
And now what I'm trying to do is to make it clickable.
I've set up a RelativeLayout behind the ImageView and I'm trying to rotate the layout using setRotation.
The layout does rotate but its inner content isn't. Is there a way of doing so without starting to create my own custom view?
All I'm trying to do is creating a rotating functional dialer menu like this one  -
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use 2 rotating imageviews on top of each other, so both of them can be rotated?

Comment: Is there really such a problem with creating your own view? You can always add a property for rotation and use that to set it on the onDraw() method

Comment: @Harry I am rotating one ImageView, but I also want to rotate a layout.

Comment: @holandaGo Well, I'm not familiar with creating views and I don't know how to rotate them, all I want to do is to rotate a LinearLayout with its content

Comment: So in other words, your ImageView is not rotating? Or is it the layout?

Comment: @Harry I have an ImageView that's rotating and I also want to rotate a RelativeLayout

Comment: As far as I know, rotating a layout is quite expensive. I don't know if there is any supporting library for this. That's why I recommend using 2 ImageViews. If you could rotate one, then you could obviously rotate the rest without having a problem.

Comment: @Harry But how can I make parts of it clickable? All I want to do is creating a rotating wheel menu/dialer

Comment: Truly I have no idea except doing this in hard way. I could tell you if you've given up looking for easy solution.